# Cell notation of all aqueous solutions

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

If some redox reaction happened with no solid anode or cathode, like all aqueous solutions, something like the unbalanced reaction
$$
\ce {MnO4^- (aq) + C2O4^-^2 (aq)  -> Mn^+^2 + CO2 (aq)}
$$ What would an electrochemical cell notation represent in this situation? Is it even **logical** to try to get a cell notation? I'm really confused about that topic. I heard my professor saying something about a *platinum electrode* and I don't think this is rational by any means. Do things like this exists?

Comment: No, there is no use of a cell notation in this equation. However, the same reaction can be monitored via ORP (oxidation reduction potential) electrode which is indeed made of Pt. Search ORP electrodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to explain the use of the platinum electrodes.

If two solutions are prepared separately, one with acidic potassium permanganate, and one with sodium oxalate, they can be joined by a salt bridge. Now if one platinum plate is dipped into either solution, a potential difference can be measured between these two plates, or between these two solutions. Electrons are produced in the oxalate solution according to the half-equation :$$\ce{C2O4^{2-}-> 2 CO2 + 2 e^-}$$These electrons are collected by the platinum foil, and will go through the electric wire up to the other platinum foil dipped in the permanganate solution. Here they produce the following half-equation $$\ce{MnO4^- + 8 H^+ + 5 e^- -> Mn^{2+} + 4 H2O}$$ I should be mentioned that in the oxalate solution, the $\ce{Na^+}$ ions must quit the solution to maintain electric neutrality of the solution, and they do it by crossing the salt bridge joining the two solutions. When arriving in the permanganate solution they compensate the missing charges in solution. It takes some time to explain this movement, due to missing charges in the permanganate solution.

First, it should be mentioned that, in order to equilibrate the charges in the whole system, $10$ electrons must be produced by oxalate, and $10$ electrons must be consumed in permanganate. The corresponding half-equations become :
$$\ce{5 C2O4^{2-} -> 10 CO2 + 10 e-}$$ $$\ce{2 MnO4^- + 16 H^+ + 10 e- -> 2 Mn^{2+} + 8 H2O}$$
If the acid producing $\ce{H+}$ is $\ce{H2SO4}$, $16$ $\ce{H^+}$ ions are consumed in the half-equation. As a consequence, 8 $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ ions are left in solution, after the arrival of the electrons through the platinum foil. These $16$ negative charges in excess are compensated by

- $2$ $\ce{K^+}$ remaining after the consumption of the permanganate ions coming from $2$ $\ce{KMnO4}$,
- $2$ $\ce{Mn^{2+}}$ ions produced by the second half-reaction
- $10$ $\ce{Na^+}$ ions having crossed the salt bridge,

As a consequence, at the end of the whole process, the composition of the solutions are :

- No ions in the former oxalate solution (just some $\ce{CO2}$), and
- $\ce{2 Mn^{2+} + 2 K^+ + 10 Na^+ + 8 SO4^{2-}}$ in the former permanganate solution.

This is also the composition of the final solution one would obtain if the reaction had been done in only one phase, by mixing both solutions, with or without any platinum plates, which are now useless.

Comment: So in other words, if the reaction is carried out in two separate containers or in a single one the product will not change. However, we can make use of the electrons flow of the reaction only if we separate the two reactions with a Pt electrode in each one. And in that case the cell notation can be something like
Pt (s) | C2O4^2- (aq) | CO2 (g) || MnO4^1- (aq), Mn^2+ (aq)| Pt (s)

Comment: I am not familiar with the use of these vertical bars. But your description seems OK, but it seems to me that you have to add a vertical bar between $\ce{MnO4^-}$ and $\ce{Mn^{2+}}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that an electrode(1) in the wider sense (electrochemical half cell) consist of

- an electrode(2) in narrower sense(a conductor)
- a redox system

The electrode(2) may be

- the part of a redox system like $\ce{Zn(s)|Zn^2+(aq)}$
- or may stay aside like $\ce{Pt(s)|H+(aq)/H2(g)}$

Without at least a half cell, a cell notation does not make sense.

If more redox systems exist in parallel in the same place, they have all at assumed equilibrium the same redox potential.